# Equivalent of freopen in Java

Tags: java, file-io, freopen

Please suggest a method to obtain a similar behaviour in Java as when we do freopen("filename","r",stdin) OR freopen("filename","w",stdout) in C.

Comment: Do you have any code you've already tried?

Comment: I am new to Java. I know C++ properly. So if you could please provide a code snippet. I just know how to read from stdout through bufferedReader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this is to redirect stdin/stdout/stderr, have a look at [`System.setIn`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) and friends. They allow you to assign a different `InputStream` and `PrintStream` to `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err`.

Answer (score 2):

See the webpage below. There's a solution to what you wanna do.

http://techtipshoge.blogspot.com/2011/01/connect-standard-io-to-files.html